# Typescript add method to generic builder type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Trying to cleanup the warnings for `buildChainableHTML`. [TS Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=10&ssc=1&pln=12&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAEgKgWQDIGEAWBDAlgOwwIwBsI5wIAeOKCAD2AhwBMBnWRJAUWIFsHgA+KAF4ocAFBRJUAGRQA3lADGmXBwBufJFmb0cEAE4AuKAAoAdBYz6A5s2MAFKxl719zSgG0A5BkaN1mtq6Bl4AuvwAlMKC8Mjo2HhEJGSUggC+YmKKAPY4OlD4AK5YhIzxuATEsUjCUJTUdAwsbMhcELw4AiYQhMZwEcbV5YnEpJCp0fISUj1mygkBnVo6DAZQAPzrIuaWNnZQjvrOEK7ucN6+-hpLQav6YZGTctNSM4Rml4vAy8H6H2BgQggbqEAA0UCstgiL1eUH0J0K+hw1EIMIyr3hwERyJ6YgyWVy+QAZhhFMBsvoQDAMExiPpat1rsBjF8BlA1NksIwnjCAPS8qCMbJQZjZFxoXDWPGZIolMoqEYQaomIWKQodYBmACOhQMIAAyj0IGSKSYvEVgOScF4IgBCaGvOYKr4-O5m8mFZQ6KzALzgkkmynU2kGB1SJ0LJmuvT6d3ZT1oJp+qAB8lBmmMOlhyQR1RR24xs1ERHJ1MUqkZrMw3M4F0FgxmonZNXMUuktMVkP6bNQGt1laFrzcePMCDZDT3f3t8vBzOh6vzPOBAcNocjiCFMBtwOdufdhfO-Mr2NrwqjoUAd2tU53s6rjsXtaPvzNzEU+myhEI247d9DQA)

Is there a way to both:

- a) Satisfy the language server without workarounds (i.e. `!`,`as`, `?`)?
- b) Avoid type `HTMLChainableType` and define all generics inside the definitions of `buildChainableHTML`

```
const buildChainableHTML = <T extends HTMLElement>(el: T): HTMLChainableType<T> // this line
```

#### Code

```
type HTMLChainableType<T extends HTMLElement> = T
    & { chainEventListener: (...args: Parameters<T['addEventListener']>) => HTMLChainableType<T> }

const buildChainableHTML = <T extends HTMLElement>(el: T): HTMLChainableType<T> => {
    el.chainEventListener ??= (...args: Parameters<T['addEventListener']>) => { //  <--  squiggle under '.chainEventListener'
        el.addEventListener.apply(el, args)
        return el
    }
    return el // <-- squiggle under 'return el'
}

const factoryHandler = (event: Event): void => {
    // do something
}

buildChainableHTML(document.querySelector('button')!)
    .chainEventListener('touchstart', factoryHandler)
    .chainEventListener('touchend', factoryHandler)
    .chainEventListener('blur', factoryHandler)
    .chainEventListener('focus', factoryHandler)
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: "Avoid type `HTMLChainableType`"  Why? Anonymous recursive types are difficult or impossible to represent; what's wrong with giving the type a name?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mqknrw) meet your needs? If so I can write up an answer explaining it; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Wow! You really helped me once on another tricky TS type months ago; I'm honored!

As for the "Why" - no good reason. I just like to keep abstraction blocks compact and collected so it doesn't distract from the code flow.

Your approach definitely satisfies everything! Wasn't aware you could pre-extract `typeof` before defining values. Nice! I'll accept your answer once posted :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to write `buildChainableHTML()` in as close to a type-safe manner as I can get:

```
const buildChainableHTML = <T extends HTMLElement>(el: T) => {            
    if ("chainEventListener" in el) return el as typeof ret;
    const ret = Object.assign(el, {
        chainEventListener: (...args: Parameters<T['addEventListener']>) => {
            ret.addEventListener.apply(el, args)
            return ret;
        }
    });
    return ret;
}
```

The `el` value of type `T` that is passed into the function is not known to the compiler to be the type you were originally calling `HTMLChainableType<T>`. So you can't just start assigning to its `chainEventListener` property without the compiler complaining about it.  The easiest way to circumvent this is to use [the `Object.assign()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) with `el` as the target; this has the same effect, but the type system doesn't notice.

This also helps us because the output of `Object.assign(x, y)` is seen by the compiler to be of type `typeof x & typeof y`, so we automatically get the `HTMLChainableType<T>` type you want to see.  And so we need to use this output anywhere we need that type; we can't use `el`.  So I gave it its own name, `ret`, and we use that.

Also in order to conditionally assign the `chainEventListener` property depending on whether or not it already has one, I start with the line `if ("chainEventListener" in el) return el as typeof ret;`.  That [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) is necessary because there's no guarantee at the type level that an `el` with an existing `chainEventListener` member actually has one of the type you're expecting.  For all you know someone passes in `Object.assign(document.createElement("div"), {chainEventListener: true})` for `el`.  In order to avoid having to name the `HTMLChainableType<T>` there, I used [the `typeof` type operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html) on `ret`.  That works because the scope of the typing for `ret` is the whole function, even though you can't actually the value there.  If that didn't work you could have done `as never` and it wouldn't change the function typing.

But personally I'd suggest just removing that line entirely.  I can't imagine it'll matter much if you happen to re-assign the `chainEventListener` property on an element that already has one, and it makes the function implementation cleaner.

---

Let's make sure it works as expected.  What is the type signature?

```
/* const buildChainableHTML: <T extends HTMLElement>(el: T) => T & {
    chainEventListener: (...args: Parameters<T["addEventListener"]>) => T & ...;
} */
```

That `...` ellipsis is the quickinfo engine giving up because it's an anonymous recursive type.  Personally, I find this unpleasant, since there is no valid way to refer to this type.  I'd much rather see a named type like `HTMLChainableType<T>`.  That lets other people talk about it; that lets you [generate type declaration files](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#declaration); that lets you inspect the type.  But this was part of your requirement so that's what you've got.

Let's keep going:

```
const chainable = buildChainableHTML(document.querySelector('button')!);
/* const chainable: HTMLButtonElement & {
    chainEventListener: (type: string, listener: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject, 
      options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions | undefined) => HTMLButtonElement & ...;
} */
```

Okay, that looks good also, I think.  Let's make sure the chaining works:

```
const c = chainable
    .chainEventListener('touchstart', factoryHandler)
    .chainEventListener('touchend', factoryHandler)
    .chainEventListener('blur', factoryHandler)
    .chainEventListener('focus', factoryHandler)
    .chainEventListener('mouseover', factoryHandler)
    .chainEventListener('mouseup', factoryHandler)
    .chainEventListener('mousedown', factoryHandler)
    .chainEventListener('scroll', factoryHandler)

/*
const c: HTMLButtonElement & {
    chainEventListener: (type: string, listener: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject, 
      options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions | undefined) => HTMLButtonElement & ...;
}
*/
```

That compiles with no error, and the compiler still sees that `c` is of the same type as `chainable` (at least to the extent that we believe `...` refers to the same type wherever we see it).

So there you go!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBARgVwJYBsAmBhAFgQyWHOFAUwAkAVAWQBkYBeGAHnJmIA8piw0IYKaAoiQC2XKAD4AFMRQAuGOQCU9cTADeAKA0wdMJADMYkgETBc+AQDcx1JNC7EATsb1hWKZY+JQEjtzJgcXigATwAHYhBDLygAbm1dAHpEmABadIzMrOyc3NTVAD0i4pLihJ1kmChcWCCIJygkcD1eMGJgYggIHEcQ+HacBHqqrCdiAHJWkBgAcwQenDBOYhGcKHKYSoC7QJQvHDQ+qJGVtE6kLzQq8JXiazcDPVhcXhwYMzwwKxs7TjbHGBhRwgMIbSoABScEHAOBQKD6AElxlcvMIQNYToE4OiVih8LclhcZCEtLp3uBoDAYvQYAB5OAAK3aUAAdHUkDMwNIUAAadQbMkfCz3KC2ez-eSSFnSnozCDycELUScRwQZgAbXGBzQ3yWYr+TnGAF1xMo6KpNGSrboYmy0DqRfqHI42WEwvDuXzZRBFALrVTvL43DF4v6YABfDbhxShm2BvwBuIaSOJABU5MgsEQqEw5gIRDIVGo8mYrA4XB4fCLQmIoiWUhk8iUKgUMAAZPzBXndaLfs7JdK2Y45Qqld4oRrjNqe07-sYTWbVCwO4P4uGYKnElpQJmYPocMAoCBeqRFmgSACGNIRfIe4p5JYQEgrubO0kUmhptDlVh8DNk9uFKwEK+YkDS2boNgnyECQ-DUJIn7AAgdasgAjggTghAAyjIzLHpI4yIFAR5gOMigAIQxhoaYZpSIEwcQ8hwQAQggxHgDWKHtm+OggTOfYSkYoQRPI0COH+fJ4uKTi3o6AlOLSjj8dJjj0kyh58n6IKNBSAD88jYiAJCLDAAA+MAAIL2spBqqWEOmQGZMAINwxD6PiaCLlWNCsexXwiGI3GrsmG5boBu7ADS9EFhsLJ8XJKkEUeCBmNAPRQOMfL7oex4hKe3AXr6ZJxd2CW2UlIApaM3CZXuB5HieZ6FbF8U-IlhEoL4tXZQ1eVNU4RW6CVnw2c6BH6CASEQN19W5fl54DS1pVteV4xokMkTWI4M05Y1BWLcVrV6vJjgEet9QIGEO29fNzWHctx3tedxCfgA7qRWWzXtC2OINOjDcKK1jZMwDAnC11zf1v1aGmGg7nRTFFr5JGcYFHaWroR29ipkrCYxMBiRJMBSbZslA-8imjRTjLMny2lNJA+nwCARnECZ5lWQ65MKfZDO8OZLlnO5bSeS2LFsSjAVLEF0prhom5AA)